# Android Imageview positioning to cover the display without stretching

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a horizontal image which is more wide than tall. I want the image to fill the display fully heightwise and I do not care if the sides get clipped out as it is the center of the image that is important to be seen.

When the android device gets turned to its side, the user should be able to see much more of the image since its a horizontal picture on a horizontal display.

I've been using fill_parent and match_parent and fill content and testing all of these over and over by exporting them to my phone. It is all drastically different from the virtual device verses my phone.

**edit: main idea is to cover the entire display when the device is both held horizontal and vertical**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/honktext"
        android:onClick="amazinghonks"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/big_clown" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/toptext"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#33B5E5" 
    android:background="#CC303030"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or this?

```
imageView.setScaleType( ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP );
```

Comment: Yep, use centerCrop as the scale type. This is the correct answer :)

Comment: Do I get rid of layout_width and height? Or just add it in. Let me try exporting to my nexus.

Comment: That worked! However, I think I See an on click listener kind of giving me a small 5dp margin along the sides that I cant seem to get rid of.

Comment: Add **android:padding="0dp"** to your ImageButton